# Catch the exception thrown at client side when the server closed the pipe

Tags: c#, exception, pipe

I checked similar questions but my question seems simpler and straightforward:
There are a server and a client and a named pipe between.

The client listens to the messages the server sends (while loop).

How do I detect that the server closed the pipe, so I softly close the client as well?

I saw 3 options:

1. Put `pipeHhandle.IsClosed` in the `while` condition of the listening client loop
2. Catch `ObjectDisposedException` hoping that it will catch only end of communication and not other failures (This exception does not give exception `errorCode`).
3. Catch `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception` and check inside the exception `errorCode` (-2147467259). Is it standard to put an "if" in catch code?

I did not find any specific exception for "ended pipe" although the program (without catch) does throw an exception whose number is 109 or -2147467259, I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

the most common way to know that the other side is dead is the "echo":
once in a while(let's say every 10 seconds) the client sends an "echo" - meaning a simple request to the server to get replay. if 3 echo in a row(could be more, depend on you) did not answered by the server, the client decide that the server is down and disconnect his side